# Slide to bottom 0 after X seconds

Tags: jquery, delay, slide

There is a black absolute div at the bottom bottom:-220px; (with class="tf_content").
It needs to automaticly slide to bottom:0 after X seconds.

Here is the (one page) [website](http://www.naamfaam.graffx.nl/)

The script would look a little like this???:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tf_content")
        .animate({bottom: -220px})
        .delay(4000)
});
```

Also I need to reset it after loading a new div with that class?, see website.

Comment: I changed the delay to 6 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#load_limit").slideUp(600)
                  .delay(6000)
                  .slideDown(600);
});


<div id="load_limit">some value here</div>
```

div { height:100px; background:red; }

Something like this?

edit to your own specs...

http://jsfiddle.net/xjEy5/2/

Comment: He needs 5 or 8 seconds delay

Comment: Here is a slide up and slide down function based on document.ready (function)

Comment: Ok, starting to look like i'm getting there, only why doesn't this work? http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/xjEy5/19/

Comment: Hi Sup, that works but I need it to go from bottom:-220px to bottom 0 after lets say 4 seconds so it is hidden.

Second problem will be when I load a other contentfield on my website the div needs to be visible again.

Answer (score 2):

Slide down is used for showing something, not hiding it.

since your using absolute positioning, try something like

```
$(".tf_content").animate({bottom: -220px}, 500)
```

**EDIT:**

Use height instead

```
$(".tf_content").delay(5000).animate({    height: "0px",  }, 500 );
```

Comment: you are right, but i think there is something wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/fourroses666/xjEy5/19

Comment: I think Racura's would work as well, just set your height and speed.

Comment: Thank you, script works, but it seems that I have a problem with it on my site. I use a other script which adds style="display:block" and hidden for the other ones. See source when you slide thru the projects. I really don't know any solutions, i'm not a coder. 

Maybe it is possible to say when the div tf_content gets display:block then slide down after the x seconds?

Answer (score 0):

why use WINDOW?
use

```
 setTimeout(show_popup, 5000);
```

or just

```
$(".tf_content").delay(5000).slideDown();
```

Comment: Using `setTimeout` instead of `window.setTimeout` shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: you are right , it was not warning just notice fore Code to look more readable shorter and nicer .

Comment: if you want to slide it down after 5 seconds since page loads put it inside $(document).load(function(){ JUST HERE });